# Where can I start Headless Js service on native code of React native

Tags: react-native, headless

I implement **Headless** Js for background task, but my knowledge about native code not ok, I created my backgroud service but don't know where can I put the code to start it, I try to put it on **onCreate** of **MainApplication.java** but app crash immediately when run, where can start my background service, thanks.
I implement folow [this guide](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/headless-js-android.html)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add the code to start service in MainApplication.java "onCreate()" method.

1. Instead, add a module that is exposed to ReactNative code. Then call the method from React-Native: [Follow this guide](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android)
2. Add a Broadcast receiver that listens to messages, and start the service. Whenever the service is invoked, HeadlessJS executes the task in react-native.